# How to setup a negative constant in schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema trying to validate a port number and it is being compared to a reference to a port definition and a constant value of negative 1.

When evaluating a port value (21915) it says th at the value is valid under each of the the checks mentioned above (const and port).

I have changed the value to be 0 and -1 and it does not complain, but once it's bigger than 0 it starts the issue again.

Port is defined as follows in a separate file:

```
...
"port": {
"type": "number",
"multipleOf": 1.0,
"minimum": 1,
"maximum": 65535
},
....
```

The way the check is set up is as follows:

```
"oneOf": [
     {"$ref": "schemaFile.json#/port"},
     {"const": -1},
     {"type": "null"}
]
```

Error says:

`21915.0 is valid under each of {"const": -1}, {"$ref": "schemaDef.json#/port"}`

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is correct. I suspect that the problem is that you're using a validator that doesn't support the `const` keyword. `const` was added in JSON Schema draft-06, so if you're validator is way back on draft-04, you might get this error. Unknown keywords are ignored, so that subschema effectively has no constraints and will always pass. Therefore, if the value passes the first or third schema, you'll always get an error for `oneOf` because more than one of the subschemas are passing.

Assuming that I'm right that you're on draft-04, you can use `"enum": [-1]` in place of `"const": -1` and things should work as you expect.

Comment: I am using draft-07, I changed it to `"enum": [-1]` and it did not complain. Not sure what is causing this issue when using const.

Answer (score 1):

You have competing constraints on the `port` definition and the `oneOf`

`const: -1` contradicts your `minimum` and `maximum` but otherwise, the schema seems to pass your requirements.

#### passing instances

```json
{
"port": 1
}
```

```json
# I don't think you expect this but the const -1 overrides the min/max constraints
{
"port": -1
}
```

```json
{
"port": 21965
}
```

```json
{
"port": null
}
```

Comment: I see, then why did it work fine when using the `enum = [-1]`? A little confused about this.

Comment: a port will never be -1, but you are adding that possibility with `const/enum`. That logically conflicts with your min max constraints though .it's not clear what you mean by "it works"  the reason Jason recommended `enum` is because earlier JSON Schema drafts didn't use the keyword `const`. It's effectively the same behavior with the way he described.

Comment: Well, the value comes from a spreadsheet and -1 is valid because it represents something in our code, it disables some data transfers. It does not come from a process in the machine. 

By "it works" I mean that it did not complain about 21915.0 being valid under each of...
This is confusing because const and enum should be equivalent.

Comment: If you're passing `21915.0` to the `oneOf` then it's correctly passing based on your schema.  It shouldn't throw an error.  It satisfies the first subschema which is a ref to `port` and doesn't fail the other two.